# Showing value in form fields if class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

When the form fields are inputted and submitted (`#submit_btn`) correctly my values disappear. When they are not valid this doesn't happen. I have tried fixing this with jQuery:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
    if($("#register .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok") === true) {
        $('#name-007').val('Full Name').show();
        $('#email-007').val('Email').show();
        $('#phone-007').val('Phone Number').show();
    }
});
```

but it is not working.

Edit: `#register` is parent and `.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok` is child

Any ideas?

Comment: `$("#register .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok")` is a jQuery-wrapped object that can't be strictly `===` evaluated to true or false. which element is `$("#register .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok")` ?

Comment: use the .hasClass() inbuilt function -- .https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood this should work for you:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
    if($("#register .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok")) {
        $('#name-007').val('Full Name').show();
        $('#email-007').val('Email').show();
        $('#phone-007').val('Phone Number').show();
    }
});
```

checking `$("#register .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok")` with `true` will not work as it is a dom object which is truth-sy but not strictly same as `true`

Comment: Can you please explain why exactly the logic : true/false doesn't work?

Comment: Because that `$("#register .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok")` will return the array of objects, which is not the same type of data as true (boolean) is, the data type is different, will result in if condition to be true while using strict ===.

Comment: In javascript, 0 is false, everything else is true(in our case the array of objects)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
    if($("#register .wpcf7-mail-sent-ok").length) {
        $('#name-007').val('Full Name').show();
        $('#email-007').val('Email').show();
        $('#phone-007').val('Phone Number').show();
    }
});
```

This is the "proper" way of checking if element exists.
No need for using " > 0" or "==="

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function() {
    if($("#register").hasClass("wpcf7-mail-sent-ok") {
        $('#name-007').show();
        $('#email-007').show();
        $('#phone-007').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You are missing " at the end of 'if' :)

Comment: I think `#register` don't have that class, it have a child with that class, as per op

Comment: Yes, register has a child, so maybe using .children("wpcf7-mail-sent-ok") could work?